# ng-show value will not update inside itself by clicking ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dropdown, ng-show

I have this problem where I am trying to do a dropdown-menu using `ng-show`. My HTML looks something like:

```html
<div class="dropdown" ng-mouseover="test()" ng-mouseleave="test2()" ng-click="test3()">
       <span>{{dropDownTimeEst}}</span>
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down bron-caret" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <div class="dropdown-content" ng-show="showDropwDownTime">
           <a ng-repeat="item in times" ng-click="changeTimeEst(item)">{{item}}</a>
       </div>
</div>
```

The point is that whenever I hover or click on the dropdown box it shows me the dropdown-content. I manage to open the dropdown-content successfully but when clicking on item and triggering the changeTimeEst function the ng-show doesnt update in scope.

Controller code:

```js
$scope.test = function(){
    $scope.showDropwDownTime = true;
}
$scope.test2 = function(){
    $scope.showDropwDownTime = false;
}
$scope.test3 = function(){
    $scope.showDropwDownTime = true;
}
$scope.changeTimeEst = function(item){
    $scope.dropDownTimeEst = item;
    $scope.showDropDownTime = false; //This here does not do anything, but it should close the dropdown-content
```

Does anyone have ideas how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Typo `$scope.showDropDownTime = false;`  should be `$scope.showDropwDownTime = false;`

Comment: Did the typo here but in my application the variables are the same and it is still not working.

Comment: can you please provide the sample json object also in OP. So that it will easy to look into the issue

Comment: you have two separate directives competing with each other here. the `ng-mouseover` function is causing the value to continue to be true, even though the `ng-click` tries to change the value.  The moment that the `$digest` is triggered, the `ng-mouseover` fires again.  This is more easily demonstrated with an example that separates the `ng-show` into a separate `div` that isn't affected by `ng-mouseover`... http://plnkr.co/edit/77h2M9n4fhPBTTheXF5o?p=preview

Comment: even if remove the ng-mouseover and leave it still gives me the rootScope inprog error, any ideas what could be causing this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi I think your click event is propagating to outside div. So, you should stop propagation of this event.
Try this :

```
<div class="dropdown" ng-mouseover="test()" ng-mouseleave="test2()" ng-click="test3()">
       <span>{{dropDownTimeEst}}</span>
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down bron-caret" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <div class="dropdown-content" ng-show="showDropwDownTime">
           <a ng-repeat="item in times" ng-click="changeTimeEst(item); $event.stopPropagation();">{{item}}</a>
       </div>
</div>
```

As, you can see I have added **$event.stopPropagation()** on your anchor click event.
Hope, this solves your problem :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks @OskarMartin

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you've mispelled your variable in your view's `ng-show`. Either that or you've mispelled it in your controller's `$scope.changeTimeEst()` function. I'm not sure which one you want.

You have:

```
ng-show="showDropwDownTime"
```

I think you want:

```
ng-show="showDropDownTime"
```

If however, you've just made a typo when copying your code over to StackOverflow, then you're most likely in need of something different. In that case, I would suggest using `$scope.$apply()` to trigger a digest cycle and tell the view that you have updated a variable in your controller's scope.

For example:

```
$scope.changeTimeEst = function(item) {
     $scope.dropDownTimeEst = item;
     $scope.showDropDownTime = false;
     $scope.$apply(); // This should update your view
}
```

Comment: Sorry I had the typo in this post, but in my application all the variables are the same. Still no change. I have tried the apply thing aswell but it gives me error : Error: [$rootScope:inprog]